# MAMP (installed on account 1) doesn't open on account 2

Tags: mamp, account

One year ago, I installed MAMP 3.5 on my husband's MacBookAir (10.10.5) and I created a complete site woth WordPress. Since then I have opened another account (User2) on this Mac and I worked on-line but when I try to open MAMP on User2's account, no way.

I try "Démarrer les serveurs", it doesn't want to switch on.

Comment: You can include the English translation of the error you are getting.

Comment: avoid "démarrer les serveurs" stuff in your question also, this is an english speaking website, most people won't understand french stuff